# dual screen setup in ubuntu with Intel HD graphics

Tags: xorg, xserver

I have a ubuntu machine with integrated Intel HD Graphics with 2 monitors plugged into the two ports provided. With this setup both the monitors have exaclty same output. I needed to extend the X server's functionality to support one more screen so that when I run some application it runs either on screen0 or on screen1.

To do this I added a file name monior.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d directory but does not work for me. The file looks like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier    "DualScreen"
    Screen        0 "Screen0"
    Screen      1 "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Card0"
    Driver        "intel"
    BusID        "PCI:00:02.0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Card1"
    Driver        "intel"
    BusID        "PCI:00:02.0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Screen0"
    Device        "Card0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Screen1"
    Device        "Card1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
EndSection
```

But this doesn't work. The output of xrandr is as following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 900, current 1280 x 900, maximum 1280 x 900
default connected 1280x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x900        0.0*
```

What I need is two screens independent of each other and windows can not be moved between them. Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is [here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Dual_Monitors).
At the time of this writing, this site is down, but fortunately, [The Grand Way Back Machine still has it](http://web.archive.org/web/20130429073111/http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Dual_Monitors#Single_graphics_card.2C_Multiple_X_screens_with_ZaphodHeads).

This works for me, but unfortunately GNOME 3 does not support multiple X screens.

To Summarize, the necessary steps to get two X screens on intel graphics are:

- Two Device Sections with

  - `Option         "ZaphodHeads" "`*yourdevice*`"`

    - *yourdevice* as given by `xrandr`
  - `Option         "AccelMethod" "sna"`
- Two Screen Sections referring to the Device Identifiers

This is my (almost-minimal) sample config

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen         "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen         "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "0:2:0"
    Option         "ZaphodHeads" "eDP1"
    Option         "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Screen         0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "0:2:0"
    Option         "ZaphodHeads" "DP1"
    Option         "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Screen         1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
EndSection
```

Comment: If I could upvote you a thousand times, I would -- this has gotten me 99% of the way to a solution I've been seeking for literally months. Thanks!